# Adding references to a stand alone (no Project) VB executable in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a visual basic executable in Visual Studio but NOT in a Project.  I would like to add some references (dll).  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MSBUILD, use msbuild add reference path command.

Comment: I'm using vbc.exe to compile.

Comment: underneath it uses msbuild engine, you could use msbuild /vbc parameters to add references.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the syntax, i.e., this is my command line when I use vbc.exe:   vbc.exe /t:exe /debug+ /out:.\Hello.exe Hello.vb

Comment: vbc.exe /t:library /out:abc.dll 
/r:..\xyz.Framework.dll /r:Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll 
/r:System.Data.dll abcsample.vb